# JavaScript: Why do I end up with "quotes" in my HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This rather short piece of code:

```
<div id='votmplayer'></div>
<script>

  $.getJSON('/json/votm.json', function(votmjson) {
    $.getJSON('/cgi-bin/getvideo.cgi?'+votmjson.videos[0].id, function(votmchoice) {
      document.getElementById('votmplayer').innerHTML=votmchoice.embed.code;
        });
    });

</script>
```

Is producing unexpected output. The rendered HTML shows:

```
<div id='votmplayer'>
  "<iframe src="http://www.website.com/embed/abcdefghij123456" frameborder="0" width="608" height="468" scrolling="no"</iframe>"
</div>
```

Which of course gives me the `<iframe>` as literal text. I have tried the following but the result is the same:

```
var choice = votmchoice.embed.code;
document.getElementById('votmplayer').innerHTML=choice;
```

`console.log(votmplayer)` is showing the following in Chome:

```
embed: Object
    code: "&lt;iframe src=&quot;http://www.website.com/embed/abcdefgij1234565&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;608&quot; height=&quot;468&quot; scrolling=&quot;no&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;"
```

I'm left a bit perplexed as I have used similar code elsewhere in the webpage and it is rendered correctly. I can't find anything similar around Google but maybe I'm asking the wrong question.

Comment: What's being returned from the json call?

Comment: It is being set to `votmchoice.embed.code`, so I suggest you check the value of that.

Comment: Just a little off-topic thought to your code, as you are using jQuery you might want to use jQuery functions instead of vanilla JS to make it better readable.

Comment: Out from the console added. Thanks for the quick response, everyone.

Comment: I'd suggest that the back-end (Perl) is somehow incorrect but identical works correctly elsewhere in the page.

Comment: @Tarekis Good idea, I'll look at that, thanks.

Comment: Actually... elsewhere in my code it is simply returning values not HTML. I'm guessing it is handling the HTML differently.

Comment: how about to parse only iframe url? not escaped string

Comment: I might have to do that. Each video will have varying dimensions though so it's not ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using JQuery (I'm I right?). So:
JQuery can create nodes from strings like:

```
$('<h1>Heading</h1>')
```

Which returns a JQuery DOM element. and Also it has a method to convert HTML-reduced string to HTML string and create JQuery nodes from it:

```
$('#votmplayer').html( $.parseHTML(votmchoice.embed.code)[0].textContent );
```

I've created a working [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/8k71wj0x/)

Comment: @nicael have a look at the fiddle

Comment: Now this is actually perfect.

Comment: @nicael I'm happy it helped

Comment: The result is identical.

Comment: @KenSharp But as you can see in the fiddle, I've appended an H1 heading element from a HTML escaped string. it's not a string.

Comment: @KenSharp There was a bit difference between my sample code and fiddle, I updated my answer

Comment: It's working. But is there any way to get rid of `[0].textContent` part?

Comment: Hit the nail on the head there! Thank you very much. Best answer.

Answer (score -2):

If your response text is correct this should be helpful

```
 $.getJSON('/json/votm.json', function(votmjson) {
    $.getJSON('/cgi-bin/getvideo.cgi?'+votmjson.videos[0].id, function(votmchoice) {
       if(votmchoice && votmchoice.embed && votmchoice.embed.code) {  
         $('#votmplayer').html(votmchoice.embed.code);
       }
    });
 });
```

UPDATE:

try to log `votmchoice.embed.code`

`console.log(votmchoice.embed.code);`

if it returns shows something like this `"<iframe src="http://www.website.com/embed/abcdefghij123456" frameborder="0" width="608" height="468" scrolling="no"</iframe>"`

You should fix your response from server, or just remove quotes from string like this:

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/poavu47s/1/)

```
var str = '"<iframe src="http://www.website.com/embed/abcdefghij123456" frameborder="0" width="608" height="468" scrolling="no"</iframe>"';
console.log(str.slice(1,-1));
```

Comment: This and OP's examples wouldn't make any difference if the response text was actually correct. The problem is in the response text.

Comment: The iframe would load anyway, even if there're quotes (it'll just show two quotes and the working iframe). It doesn't load apparently because all the quotes in the return string are escaped.